# Matrix multiplication with variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I go about solving this? Not sure how to isolate the variable to solve for X. Thank you for any help!

> $$\begin{pmatrix}-6&8\\2&3\end{pmatrix}X  + \begin{pmatrix}-2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2&5\\-5&8\end{pmatrix}X $$

I know that I'd have to take the inverse of the first matrix, which would give me x + the second matrix = inverse of first matrix *third matrix * x. But how would I go from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If,

$$AX+B=CX$$

Then by existence of an additive inverse ,

$$AX+B-AX=CX-AX$$

And by commutativity and associative properties of matrix addition,

$$B=CX-AX$$

And by distributive property of matrix multiplication,

$$B=(C-A)X$$

If an inverse to $C-A$ exists, and it does in our case we may multiply by it to get,

$$(C-A)^{-1}B=(C-A)^{-1}(C-A)X=IX=X$$

In conclusion,

> $$X=(C-A)^{-1}B$$

Where $C=\begin{pmatrix}-2&5\\-5&8\end{pmatrix}$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}-6&8\\2&3\end{pmatrix}$, and $B=\begin{pmatrix}-2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}$.

Hence,

> $X=\begin{pmatrix} 4&-3 \\ -7&5 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}-2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix} 5&3 \\ 7&4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 4& 16\\ 6& 22 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{pmatrix} -4& 3\\ 7& -5 \end{pmatrix} X = \begin{pmatrix} 2&2\\-2&2 \end{pmatrix} $$
The inverse matrix of $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ is $\frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{pmatrix} d& -b\\ -c& a \end{pmatrix}$ meaning the inverse of $\begin{pmatrix} -4& 3\\ 7& -5 \end{pmatrix}$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} -4& 3\\ 7& -5 \end{pmatrix} ^{-1} = -\begin{pmatrix} -5& -3\\ -7& -4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5& 3\\ 7& 4 \end{pmatrix}  $$ Let's multiply both sides of the equation with the inverse from the left:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5& 3\\ 7& 4 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} -4& 3\\ 7& -5 \end{pmatrix} X = \begin{pmatrix} 5& 3\\ 7& 4 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 2&2\\-2&2 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ X = \begin{pmatrix} 4& 16\\ 6& 22 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way to understanding this question, however it needs lots of work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv781.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZaFj.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use images of handwritten text, but use MathJax instead.